# WordPress Blogs Avatar Link/URL in Database?

Tags: database, wordpress

i was looking that where the wordpress  save the URL/Link of the Avatar of the blog in the Database of wordpress anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress uses Gravatar (Global Recognized Avatars -> see www.gravatar.com).

Gravatar is based upon the email-address. So there is no concrete link within the database for an avatar. It's based upon the posters E-Mail, which then is transformed into a gravatar-url within the wordpress-code.

Answer (score 2):

the avatar link is not saved in the database.

it is found `<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/your-emailadress-hashed-by-md5">` even Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange uses this.